# Segmentation fault using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi i'm writing some functions for a heap represented as a tree.
My Node is a struct:

```
template<typename Object>
struct Node
{
    Node * parent = nullptr;
    Object name;
    Node * left = nullptr;
    Node * right = nullptr;

    Node(Object n) : name(n){}
};
```

And my class has a private variable called root, which is the root of the tree. Here are the functions that cause an issue, specifically insert_spot:

```
template<typename Object>
void MyPriorityQueue<Object>::insert(const Object & elem) 
{
    Node<Object> n_node = Node(elem);
    Node<Object> * new_node = &n_node;
    if (cur_amount > level_amount)
    {
        cur_amount = 1;
        level += 1;
        level_amount += level_amount;
    }
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = new_node;
        cur_amount += 1;
        cur_size += 1;
        if (cur_amount > level_amount)
        {
            cur_amount = 1;
            level += 1;
            level_amount += level_amount;
        }
        return;
    }
    
    insert_spot(new_node); //insert node at bottom
}
```

And insert_spot is:

```
void insert_spot(Node<Object> * new_node)
    {
        Node<Object> * parent_node = root;
        unsigned temp_amount = cur_amount;
        while (temp_amount > 2)
        {
            temp_amount -= temp_lvl_amount;
        }
        if(temp_amount == 1)
        {
            parent_node->left = new_node;
        }
        else{parent_node->right = new_node;}
        
        new_node->parent = parent_node;
        cur_amount += 1;
        cur_size += 1;
    }
```

I know what the issue is, in the insert_spot function, when I try to do parent_node->left = new_node, or parent_node->right = new_node, a segmentation fault is given.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHbd7.png)If I substitute it with (and say Object type is int)

```
Node<Object> n_node = Node(5)
parent_node->left = &n_node;
```

same thing with parent_node->right, then it works fine.

My previous code worked, using the 'new' operator to create pointers, but I can't use that here because of some later obstacles.

I figure that the issue is with 'const Object & elem' somehow, but I can't really figure out why I can't do parent_node->left = new_node or parent_node->right = new_node.

Also just an example input from main:

```
MyPriorityQueue<int> test;
test.insert(5);
test.insert(4);
```

I'm not looking for a specific answer, just trying to understand why parent_node-> causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with `Object`.

This code

```
Node<Object> n_node = Node(elem);
parent_node->left = &n_node;
```

results very quickly in undefined behaviour. Once the `insert` function has been exited the `n_node` object is destroyed. This means your tree is holding a pointer to an object which has been destroyed. Any attempt to dereference that pointer (e.g. `parent_node->`) results in undefined behaviour.

Whatever problems you were having with `new` you are going to have to overcome them. `new` (or it's equivalent) is what is required here. You cannot use pointers to local variables to construct a tree.

The whole point about `new` is that objects created with it don't get destroyed when the scope they were created in is exited.